# Robust way to identify element type in a range (or container)

Tags: c++, c++11, range, containers

Given a range (which could be a container with begin/end iterator members), is there a robust way to determine the type of its elements?

The following works nearly all the time, but fails on ordinary arrays.

I have seen the suggestion to use the type `Container::value_type` but of course that is not defined for built-in arrays.

Somehow the code below fails to find `begin(int [3])` when compiled with GCC 4.8.1.  It does work with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Identify the type of element in given range type.
template<typename Range> struct range_elem {
    typedef typename std::decay<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Range>()))>::type type;
};

// Count the number of elements in range matching value.
template<typename Range>
int count(const Range& range, typename range_elem<Range>::type value) {
    int n = 0;
    for (const auto& e : range) { if (e==value) n++; }
    return n;
}

struct S { };
int count(S&, int) { return 10; }  // further test robustness to overload

int main() {
    // This compiles OK.
    std::vector<int> vec; vec.push_back(1); vec.push_back(2); vec.push_back(3);
    std::cerr << count(vec, 2) << "\n";
    //
    int ar[3] = {1,2,3};
    // This compiles OK.
    {
        int n = 0;
        for (const auto& e : ar) { if (e==2) n++; }
        std::cerr << n << "\n";
    }
    // This fails to compile on gcc 4.8.1;
    //  error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int [3])'
    std::cerr << count(ar, 2) << "\n";
    //
    // Somehow realize SFINAE when overloading with a different type that does not support begin/end?
    S s; std::cerr << count(s,2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is because `std::begin` only works on `T(&)[N]` not `T[N]`.

Comment: @nijansen That is really wonderful; many thanks!  I just have one more complication.  Please see the edit in the question above.  If the function is overloaded, is there a way to achieve SFINAE so that the compiler ignores the function if the range argument does not contain begin/end members?

Comment: @nijansen I was able to make it SFINAE by defining a macro `#define ELEM_TYPE(T) typename std::decay<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>::type`.  It seems ugly to have to do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, notice that `std::begin(ar)` is valid. In fact `typename std::decay<decltype(*std::begin(ar))>::type` is valid as well. So the problem must lie elsewhere.

It becomes clear when you look at how `std::begin` is implemented, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T * begin(T (& arr)[N])
{
    return arr;
}
```

So it works for `T(&)[N]` but not for `T[N]`, which is unfortunately what `decltype(ar)` is deduced to.

Your code compiles if you change it to:

```
template<typename Range> struct range_elem {
    typedef typename std::decay<
        decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Range &>()))
    >::type type;
};
```

See here: http://ideone.com/RoNFZz

---

In your updated question, you ask for a way to use SFINAE to detect whether your type is compatible to `std::begin`. You could easily write a trait for that:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_begin
{
    typedef char (& yes)[1];
    typedef char (& no)[2];

    template <typename U>
    static yes deduce(decltype(std::begin(std::declval<U const &>())) *);
    template <typename> static no deduce(...);

    static bool constexpr value = sizeof(deduce<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Or full code here: http://ideone.com/W9GLSt

Comment: That works great, and your answer provides many insights in using the new C++11 features.  Thanks!